# jQuery function doesn't return values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting the wrong calculation and the function doesn't return the 3 values from `.investment` elements so that I'll be able to calculate them and output them into `.payout` elements. What am I doing wrong here?

```js
function investmentArray() {
  $('.investment').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text().slice(0, -2);
    text = parseFloat(text.replace(/,/g, ''));
    text = Number(text);
    return text;
  });
};

function payoutCalc() {
  var i = investmentArray();
  return i * 1.8;
}

var payoutArray = function() {
  var el = $('.payout');
  el.each(function() {
    var result = Number(payoutCalc()).toFixed(2);
    $(this).html(result + " $");
  });
}
payoutArray();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Investment</th>
    <th>Payout</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="investment">1,937.00 $</td>
    <td class="investment">285.00 $</td>
    <td class="investment">1,926.00 $</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="payout"></td>
    <td class="payout"></td>
    <td class="payout"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem is that you are trying to return from jquery `.each()` loop. You need to pass the index and get elements instead of using loop that.

> To break a $.each loop, you have to return false in the loop callback.
>   Returning true skips to the next iteration, equivalent to a continue in a normal loop.

```js
function investmentArray(c) {
  text = $('.investment').eq(c).text().slice(0, -2);
  text = parseFloat(text.replace(/,/g, ''));
  text = Number(text);
  return text;
};

function payoutCalc(c) {
  var i = investmentArray(c);
  return i * 1.8;
}

var payoutArray = function() {
  var el = $('.payout');
  el.each(function(i, val) {
    var result = Number(payoutCalc(i)).toFixed(2);
    $(this).html(result + " $");
  });
}
payoutArray();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Investment</th>
    <th>Payout</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="investment">1,937.00 $</td>
    <td class="investment">285.00 $</td>
    <td class="investment">1,926.00 $</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="payout"></td>
    <td class="payout"></td>
    <td class="payout"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow! That was quick! Thank you so much sir! I think I need to study more about loops! :)

Comment: @Randy It is not a problem in normal for loop. But in case of jQuery each, when you return, that means it either breaks loop or continues loop. It wont return value to the outer function.